# What is domain logic?

Tags: architecture, terminology, business-logic

What is domain logic?  The Wikipedia page for domain logic redirects to business logic.  Are they the same thing, and, if not, how do they differ?

Comment: Here's a blog post on that topic: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/08/25/what-is-domain-logic/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The domain is what you are modelling.

If you are modelling a business problem, they are the same thing.

If you are modelling something else, physics for instance, there is probably no business logic in your system, but the physics parts are still domain logic.

Comment: Is business logic a subset of domain logic? This seems to contradict Brian Knoblauch's answer, if so

Comment: I wouldn't call Brian Knoblauch's answer incorrect, it is just a slightly narrower view of the concept. If you are building a CRM system, then your problem domain is CRM and your domain logic is business logic specific to the area of CRM.

Answer (score 47):

Domain is the world your application lives in. So if you are working on say a flight reservation system, the application domain would be flight reservations.

Business Logic on the other hand is a more discrete block of the entire Application Domain. Business Logic is usually a section of code built to perform one specific business process. So you would have business logic to take a reservation. Another bit of business logic would be code to refund cancelled tickets.

The objects that support your business process then become your business objects!

Answer (score 23):

Business logic is teleological (concerned with how to achieve an objective) while domain logic is ontological (what exists, or the object model that's used to reason with)

Comment: If they were to be different, I think this would be the best answer as to how. Domain logic would encapsulate your different domain objects and their relation to one another. While Business Logic would describe how each object uses those relations to achieve a specific objective.

Comment: The clearest answer so far, thanks! So, in this regard, data layer would concern itself with the persistence (and access, query etc.) of objects of the domain logic, right?

Answer (score 9):

Let's cover a scenario.

You have a client for XYZ restraint and he wants you to make his system online.
Where user can place an order online, track them, make payment etc.

For a client point of view this system would be called **Business Idea**
while "place order online" said to be one of the **business process** and
if user place order online, client wants each detail of user, want to display it on screen etc said to be **Business logic**.

Now you will model his business idea into your point of view in a way that your system can accomplish his all business process or his complete business idea said to be **Problem Domain** or **Application Domain** or **Domain of your Application**.

Now you will first identify all the business processes. And identify entities or object to accomlish business processes. Those object said to be **Business Obect** or **Domain Object** and method or logic that implement business process like placeOrder said to be **Domain Logic**.

So **business logic** is what client wants because its in client business domain and **domain logic** is how you implement it. because it's in your application domain.

Comment: The best answer, everything is clearly written, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Domain logic applies to the problem domain, e.g. "order processing". Domain logic is about  the entities you work with (the object model), and their relationships.

Business logic contains rules specific to your context, e.g. "orders from customers of group X are to be processed using discount Y when exceeding amount Z". Business "logic" is about encoding facts about your business (or the business of the customer who uses the program).

Answer (score 3):

Business logic specific to one particular field/area of expertise.

Comment: So is domain logic a subset of business logic? This seems to contradict jakber's answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the Business Logic is related to:

Any logic or association between entities in the Domain.

So how does a Student relate to a Class or a Student.
How is a new Class created and how do you Register a Student for that Class

Anything to do with business rules, determining outcomes, services, events, processes, calculations, transformation and related data manipulations/creation.

I have found it hard to find good books/teachers to help structure domain logic. It's easy to structure the domain. But domain logic seems to me a place no one wants to go.

Answer (score 0):

My domain is pharmaceutical. It deals in compartments, doses, differential equations, and statistics. If you want to call that my "business", then I guess it's "business logic".

Answer (score 0):

- Business logic is concerned with coordinating valid interactions between view and model (ui and data).
- Domain Logic is about keeping an internally consistent model representation on both sides of the app (client and server).