# Business Logic in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

1. What exactly a Business Logic is?
2. In MVC which part consists Business Logic?
3. Is that service part of MVC works as Business Logic(for example CRUD operations)?
4. what is the better(or best) approach to implement Business Logic in Web applications?

Comment: I'm voting to close at this is extremely broad, not directly programming related and partly answered in other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273800/what-are-business-objects-and-what-is-business-logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Business Logic:The overall set of rules that determine how the data  will be stored or manipulated in a  business or application domain.

2.The Model-View-Controller (MVC): An architectural pattern that separates an application into three main logical components: the model, the view, and the controller. The data associated with the underlying business logic is represented by Model. The UI logic of the application is represented by View layer.The Service layer or Controllers act as an interface between Model and View components to process all the business logic and incoming requests, manipulate data using the Model component and interact with the Views to render the final output.

3.The service layer or controller infact represents the core business logic for the data manipulation represented by CRUD operations.

4.For larger web applications the best approach is to keep minimal amount of code in each layer and a seperate layer is added centered around the business logic. This layer is termed as a business logic layer. For smaller applications the database objects itself could contain the business logic.